Why spring boot not generate table
Hello  I'm working on a project using Spring Boot and PostgreSQL, and I'm encountering an issue with creating the table in the database.
I've defined an entity Users with fields userId and username. I've properly configured the datasource settings in the application.properties file.
Despite this, when I start the application, the table isn't created in the database, and I don't see any errors in the console.
Could you please help me understand what might be the issue? I've checked the configurations, and everything seems to be correct, so I'm unsure why the table isn't being created.
Thank you in advance for your assistance.
Java Code:
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Users {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer userId;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;
}

# DataSource settings
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/ishotit
spring.datasource.username=ishotit
spring.datasource.password=apipassword

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG

# RabbitMQ settings
rabbitmq.username=guest
rabbitmq.password=guest
rabbitmq.host=localhost
rabbitmq.port=5672
rabbitmq.queueFile=queueFile
rabbitmq.topic=topic


Do you have entity scanning enabled for your @SpringBootApplication i.e. @EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.yourpackage.entities"})?

You might need to add spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver to your application.properties

Try using @Table(name="users"). I think this is happening because user is a reserved keyword in PostgreSQL.
